# List Of Long Running Services C#

Tags: c#

How can I get a list of long running services on my current machine?

I can list all processes but how can I add to filter long running ones?

```
private void ListProcesses()  
{  
    Process[] processCollection = Process.GetProcesses();  
    foreach (Process p in processCollection)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I think you should define 'long running process' first

Comment: Long runing = for long time ? the earlier ?

Comment: If you are talking actual wall time, then you can use each processes `StartTime` to figure out how long they've been running and filter to ones above whatever threshold you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can list all processes but how can I add to filter long running ones?

Something like (assuming you are asking for wall time):

```
foreach (var p in processCollection.Where(n => (DateTime.Now - p.StartTime) > someThresholdInterval))
{
   //...long running
}
```

There are other properties you could also use like [TotalProcessorTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.totalprocessortime(v=vs.110).aspx) which would give you the total amount of time that the process has actually been using the processor (versus sleeping) which might be more interesting in some cases.

If you actually want services, rather than processes, then there is a different method to get those. To get services use [ServiceController.GetServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) however, I don't think there's a way to get when they started.

Answer (score 2):

The Process class has a datetime property Process.StartTime that gets the time that the associated process was started.
You could use it to figure out which ones that run for longer.

Answer (score 1):

for running services only, we must use ServiceController and ManagementObject  . here is my code for "long" running services :

```
 static public void Main()
        {
            TimeSpan Interval = new TimeSpan(5,0,10); // as exemple

            var scServices= ServiceController.GetServices();

            foreach (ServiceController scTemp in scServices)
            {
                if (scTemp.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                {
                    ManagementObject wmiService;
                    wmiService = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" + scTemp.ServiceName + "'");
                    wmiService.Get();

                    var id = Convert.ToInt32(wmiService.Properties["ProcessId"].Value);
                    Process p = Process.GetProcessById(id);

                    if ((DateTime.Now.Subtract(p.StartTime)) > Interval)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("  Service :        {0}", scTemp.ServiceName);
                        Console.WriteLine("  Display name:    {0}", scTemp.DisplayName);
                        Console.WriteLine("  StartTime:       {0}", p.StartTime);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```